# How to create a basic package to store images?

Tags: c#

How can I create a basic package to store images, like a zip file?

All I want to do is to store 20000 images inside one package. It will be easier for my hard disk.

Also, I need to be able to enter and exit from that package, read/write , add/remove files, using C# code.

Another file format is .iso that is close to what I want, but is complicated to operate with.

I want something very basic, not complicated. Basic as a library if possible.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to get. you can embed the images inside your c# project. Read about [Embedded Resource](http://www.vcskicks.com/embedded-resource.php).

Comment: Have you considered using a virtual hard disk? From your perspective in essence it is the same as an ISO file.

Comment: not embedding inside the code. Probably I will not be able to embed more than 5Mb anyway. I have 20000 images at very low rezolution, but they weight 100Mb.

Comment: Zip files are supported by the .NET framework through https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.7.1 which could fit your use case...

Comment: to pepitosh. A virtual hard disk sounds very cool. Is easy to setup? to transport to other computers? is general enough? I want as basic as possible. But i like your idea - i will give it more thought if nothing will come out. Thanks!

Comment: to sirdarius. I tried already zip files. I want something more simple than that. More basic if possible. No archiving needed, only storage. Like a box !!!

Comment: @teodoric8. you can use the @ symbol if you want to ping users, they will receive a notification that you responded.

Comment: Please use @ to mention users. A zip file without compression is one of the simplest ways of storing files within a single file. It is supported natively by the .NET framework. I cannot really imagine anything simpler. Could you please specify why you ruled out this solution?

Comment: @SirDarius I am not ruling out anything. I am just curious what else is out there. Alternatives. I am sure there are some. My hope is to find something more basic than the common used ones.  I also would be curious if it is possible to make a box/package like that on my own, from scratch. If you have any code in mind, please shoot.

Comment: @Martin Verjans thank you for re-edit my original question. It looks better now, indeed. Also, thank you to those who point out how to use the @ sign.

Comment: @teodoric8. You're welcome. However I'm afraid your question doesn't really fit a proper question on StackOverflow, because you're asking for a tool, which is [outside the scope of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then check whether your question fits in.

Comment: @ Martin Verjans Actually, I am shooting in more than one direction, on file formats for one thing, but also on libraries or some sort of code.Or methods of doing things right and easy and intuitive. So i think i still am on track.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to go with the virtual hard disk the steps are the following:
In Computer management right click Disk management and in the local menu click 'Create VHD'. Create a virtual hard disk with the parameters you prefer.  I recommend the .vhdx and dynamically expanding flavor. After this you have a mounted, un-initialized, un formatted hard drive. 
Prepare it with the necessary and usual steps. As the result you will have a hard drive with an assigned drive letter.
Use it as any hard drive you have.

After reboot it will not be automatically mounted, you have to do it manually in Disk Management or use a scheduled task to mount the drive. Here's the script for that: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-automatically-mount-d623ce34

You can unmount it at Disk Management as well.

You can copy the file yourdiskname.vhd(x) to other computers and use it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain. I do appreciate it. Very interesting way you have here. I must play with it for awhile before deciding anything. I never knew about it! Very new stuff for me - exciting. :)  I do know about a virtual space on your hdd, made with a software - a loooong time ago. Sand (box)? or dune was called...i dont remember exactly. I think I did a test back then. I think it was in the winXP era. :) This one you have here is new for me.

Answer (score 0):

### Thank you all for your input

It helped me decide and it direction me to this answer I find after many web search battles.

I find a practical solution, but not that efficient as I want it.
Is moving slow-ish when cycling the images from inside a zip file, because it is unpacking each of them. I must re-think the code and unzip all into a stream or some lists. I will see. For now, is working and I am very happy :)

Here is the result I came up with:

```
//My code so far - not very efficient but is working.
using Ionic.Zip;
using Ionic.Zlib;

        string zipPath = "0Images.zip";
        void CountZipFiles()
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipPath))
            {
                totalzipFiles = zip.Count-1;
            }
        }
        Image emptyImage = Image.FromFile("emptyFemale.jpg");
        void ReadZipImage()
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zipPath))
            {
                MemoryStream tempS = new MemoryStream();
                for (int i = 0; i &lt; zip.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (i == countMyZipImages)
                    {
                        label1.Text = zip[i].FileName;
                        if (zip[i].FileName.Contains(".niet"))
                        {
                            pictureBox1.Image = emptyImage;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            zip[i].Extract(tempS);
                            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(tempS);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int totalzipFiles = 0, countMyZipImages = 0;
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countMyZipImages--;
            if (countMyZipImages &lt; 0) countMyZipImages = totalzipFiles;
            textBox1.Text = countMyZipImages.ToString();
            ReadZipImage();
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            countMyZipImages++;
            if (countMyZipImages &gt; totalzipFiles) countMyZipImages = 0;
            textBox1.Text = countMyZipImages.ToString();
            ReadZipImage();
        }
```

---

```
// and this is a HELP file for later use - hopefully will help others too. ;)

How to add Ionic.Zip.dll in c#.net project and use it:

To add a reference, right click (in Solution Explorer on your project) Reference folder and select Add Reference.
Then browse and add the file Ionic.Zip.dll

//Important to add this using's too after referencing.
using Ionic.Zip;
using Ionic.Zlib;


        private void CreateZIP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
                zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
                // add the report into a different directory named "files" in the archive
                zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
                zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
                zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");

                Exception ex = new Exception();
                label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }


        //You can extract to a stream, or a fizical file ! 
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("0Images.zip"))
            {
                MemoryStream tempS = new MemoryStream(); //stream

          //{      
                foreach (ZipEntry ze in zip)        //foreach
                {
                    // check if you want to extract the image.name 
                    if (ze.FileName == "00002 Riley Reid.jpg")
                    {
                        ze.Extract(tempS);
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(tempS);
                    }
                }
           //OR
                for (int i = 0; i &lt; zip.Count; i++)  //for
                {
                    if (i == countMyZipImages)
                    {
                        zip[i].Extract(tempS);
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(tempS);
                    }
                }
           //}     

            }
        }
```

This is a free library I find on internet! I like it because is very little - 435kb. Here is a link I find for others if they want to use it. [Dropbox - Ionic.Zip.dll](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcqjqlfieh7r6rq/Ionic.Zip.dll)[^]